# How to get a callback when every observer of a hot like ConnectableObservable complete?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java2, multicast, observers

I am searching for a doOn... callback for a ConnectableObservable that is invoked when every observer terminates

```
       val gatewayItems = viewModel.getGatewayItems(gateways!!)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .take(1)
                .publish()
                .autoConnect(2)

            gatewayItems.subscribe { sharedGateways -> sharedGatewaysAdapter.submitList(sharedGateways) }

            gatewayItems.subscribe { sharedGateways -> privateGatewaysAdapter.submitList(privateGateways) }
```

I would like to get a callback to my multicasted hot observable when both of my observers signal a terminal event

I have tried to put doOnTerminate and doOnComplete operators on my parent multicasted observable but, it seems that these callbacks are invoked 2 times (one for each observer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   val gatewayItems = viewModel.getGatewayItems(gateways!!)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .take(1)
            .doOnComplete { ... }
            .doOnTerminate { ... }
            .publish()
            .autoConnect(2)
```

Both `.doOnComplete` and `.doOnTerminate` work for me.

Edit: the chances are you might be attaching the `do...` operators in incorrect order. For example, neither of these `doOnComplete` will work:

```
   val gatewayItems = viewModel.getGatewayItems(gateways!!)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnComplete { ... }
            .take(1)
            .publish()
            .autoConnect(2)
            .doOnComplete { ... }
```